# React-native constantly crashes on RCTKeyboardObserver event

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have constant crashes on the simulator with an event `keyboardDidChangeFrame` in `RCTKeyboardObserver`

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'bridge is not set. This is probably because you've explicitly synthesized the bridge in RCTKeyboardObserver, even though it's inherited from RCTEventEmitter.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001145091ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000112a03f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011450e372 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001124de523 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 165
    4   Ology                               0x000000010e4fef88 -[RCTEventEmitter sendEventWithName:body:] + 408
    5   Ology                               0x000000010e543544 -[RCTKeyboardObserver keyboardDidChangeFrame:] + 116
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144a4fdc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144a4eda _CFXRegistrationPost + 442
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144a4c22 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144668c2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114465a3c _CFXNotificationPost + 652
    11  Foundation                          0x00000001123e5852 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000110dfa30c -[UIInputWindowController postEndNotifications:withInfo:] + 200
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000110dfcdeb __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke_2.1049 + 84
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000110df518f -[UIInputWindowController performWithSafeTransitionFrames:] + 174
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000110dfcca6 __77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke.1042 + 921
    16  Foundation                          0x000000011245a609 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 409
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001144992a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114498f62 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114498b1a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000114490534 __CFRunLoopRun + 2308
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011448f9b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000119d6d9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001101ac5e8 UIApplicationMain + 159
    24  Ology                               0x000000010e445e7f main + 111
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011a5e0d81 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

My environment is 
XCode 9.1 (but I had this on previous versions as well)
Simulator: iPhone 6s
React-Native: 0.49.x

package.json

```
{
    "name": "Ology",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest",
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "flow": "flow",
        "flow-stop": "node_modules/.bin/flow stop",
        "translate": "babel app --plugins=react-intl",
        "tmp": "react-intl-cra './app/**/*.js' './app/resources/message'",
        "postinstall":
            "sed -i '' 's/\\[headers\\[@\"Content-Length\"\\] unsignedIntValue\\]/\\[headers\\[@\"Content-Length\"\\] intValue\\]/' ./node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTMultipartStreamReader.m",
        "eslint-check":
            "eslint --print-config .eslintrc.js | eslint-config-prettier-check"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [],
        "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
        "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./test/setupJest.js",
        "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules"],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
        }
    },
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": ["app/styles/fonts"]
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "react-native-material-kit":
            "git+https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit.git"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "autobind-decorator": "^2.1.0",
        "cheerio-without-node-native": "^0.20.2",
        "diacritic": "0.0.2",
        "expect": "^1.20.2",
        "harmony-proxy": "^1.0.1",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^2.3.1",
        "immutable": "^3.8.1",
        "jest-enzyme": "^4.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
        "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
        "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
        "lodash.mergewith": "^4.6.0",
        "lodash.sorteduniq": "^4.2.0",
        "lodash.sorteduniqby": "^4.7.0",
        "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
        "lodash.union": "^4.6.0",
        "lodash.unionwith": "^4.6.0",
        "lodash.uniqby": "^4.7.0",
        "mime-types": "^2.1.17",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "normalizr": "^3.2.3",
        "normalizr-immutable": "0.0.4-beta12",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
        "react-immutable-proptypes": "^2.1.0",
        "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
        "react-intl-redux": "^0.6.0",
        "react-native": "0.49.5",
        "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.0",
        "react-native-animatable": "^1.2.3",
        "react-native-autolink": "^1.1.1",
        "react-native-code-push": "5.1.3-beta",
        "react-native-cookies": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.1",
        "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
        "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
        "react-native-fs": "^2.5.2",
        "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.18.1",
        "react-native-immutable-list-view": "^0.6.2",
        "react-native-invertible-scroll-view": "^1.0.0",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.1",
        "react-native-keychain": "2.0.0-rc",
        "react-native-lightbox": "^0.7.0",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.3.0",
        "react-native-material-bottom-navigation": "^0.5.2",
        "react-native-material-kit": "^0.4.1",
        "react-native-modalbox": "^1.4.1",
        "react-native-parallax-scroll-view": "^0.19.0",
        "react-native-photo-view": "^1.5.2",
        "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.8.0",
        "react-native-progress": "^3.3.0",
        "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.8.0",
        "react-native-sglistview": "^0.4.3",
        "react-native-store": "^0.4.1",
        "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
        "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.13",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
        "react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.5",
        "react-swipeable-views-native": "^0.12.5",
        "realm": "^2.0.2",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-form": "^7.1.1",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-middleware-oneshot": "^0.1.1",
        "redux-persist": "^4.8.2",
        "redux-persist-immutable": "^4.3.0",
        "redux-persist-transform-immutable": "^4.3.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "reselect": "^3.0.1",
        "route-parser": "0.0.5",
        "webstomp-client": "^1.0.8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "3.0.0-beta.5",
        "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^2.3.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-airbnb": "^2.4.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
        "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
        "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
        "chai": "^4.1.0",
        "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
        "chai-enzyme": "^0.8.0",
        "chai-immutable": "^1.6.0",
        "commitizen": "^2.9.6",
        "cz-conventional-changelog": "^2.0.0",
        "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.2",
        "enzyme-to-json": "^3.1.4",
        "eslint": "^4.7.2",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
        "expect.js": "^0.3.1",
        "flow": "^0.2.3",
        "flow-bin": "^0.56.0",
        "immutablediff": "^0.4.3",
        "jest": "^21.2.1",
        "jshint": "^2.9.5",
        "mocha": "^3.4.2",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
        "react-dom": "16.0.0-beta.5",
        "react-intl-cra": "^0.2.8",
        "react-native-mock": "^0.3.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
        "redux-debounce": "^1.0.1",
        "redux-debounced": "^0.4.0",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
        "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.2",
        "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.3.0",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0",
        "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.12",
        "sinon": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a dumb mistake. I implemented it like I would on the web.

I did it like so

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.keyboardShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardDidShow);
      this.keyboardHidenListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this.keyboardDidHide);
 }

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardShowListener && this.keyboardShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardHidenListener && this.keyboardHidenListener.remove();
}
```

and it should have been

```
componentDidMount() {
  Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this.keyboardDidShow);
  Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this.keyboardDidHide);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidShow');
  Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide');
}
```